# Recovering an array

Tags: algorithm, math, data-structures, subset-sum

I recently came acrosss this question in an hiring challenge :

Given array S of 2^N integers(1 <= N <= 20, 0 <= Si <= 10^9) representing subset sums of an array A, we need to recover array A in sorted order.

e.g. S = {2, 1, 0, 3} => A = {1, 2} as subset sums of A are {0, 1, 2, 1+2}

The order of number in array S may be random.

How can I approach this problem ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any restriction on the values in A ? Can 0 be part of the array. 
Whats the range of values for A ?

Comment: No in general, but there was 0 <= Si <= 10^9

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the array containing the subset sums
When u sort the subset sum array 
A*i* = S[2^*i*] -- should give you the values of array A in sorted order.

You can make a truth table to get subset sum and trace back 
Assuming S is a valid input 
eg: S = { 0, 5, 3, 8, 1, 6, 4, 9 }

```
Sorted S = {0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9} 
A = [A0, A1, A2] --- 

A0,A1,A2 -- (Binary, part of subset = 1 not part = 0 )

Index |  A0,A1,A2  | Sorted Sum  
0        0 0 0        0
1        1 0 0        1
2        0 1 0        3 
3        1 1 0        4 
4        0 0 1        5
5        1 0 1        6
6        0 1 1        8
7        1 1 1        9

From her we can reverse and find that A0 = S[2^0], A1 = S[2^1], A2 = S[2^2]
```

Comment: I have tried it but it fails when A = {1,2,4}

Comment: Sorted S for A = {1,2,4} 

Sorted S = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7} -- this way A0 = 1, A1 = 2, A2 = 4 ?

Comment: Sorry, what if A = {1,1,1}